# Undefined Property Error on Test Cases in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Test Case fails with an error stating Undefined Property.

I'm passing roleID to getResults(). When I'm running ng test for ('it should create component').truthy, it throws an error --> undefined roleID.

I have also used in HTML like *ngIf="x?.roleID", where I'm getting the same error.

Example of `*.spec.ts` file:

```
// it('should create', () => {
//     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
//   });
// While running the ng Test for this Component, it is throwing error like ngOnit() Id of undefined property
```

Comment: Hard to see the problem, sorry. Can you try to use http://www.stackblitz.com to create a minimal demo for us to re-produce this issue, thank you

Comment: Please check this link ..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxmk8o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.inputArray` is undefined in your component, the `ngOnInit` method will fail when attempting to access the `roleID` property. During testing you will have to make sure to initialize your input, i.e. the `inputArray` property correctly, which can be done either by

**a)** wrapping your test in a test driver component that adequately sets the input, e.g. via using a template like:

`<your-component [inputArray]="validArray"></your-component>`

**b)** initializing your component attribute when preparing the test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  // assign valid array to property here:
  component.inputArray = [{roleID: 1, ...}];
  // ... your ngOnInit will be run now:
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: An example to return values for a function in Service will be much appreciated. Eg. If this.Id = this.xService.xfunction(); How should I declare a mock in testbed for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problems lie: you have no testbed and have no proper imports for your `ng test` to run.

Checking this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-testing-introduction/) to get a basic hold of it can solve your issues.

And also the [official doc in testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-class-testing).

You will have something as:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';

describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.